# Adding Field Set for Order Item

Tags: dynamic, fieldsets, orderitem

I am trying to add a field Set for OrderItem object but I can't see any way to do so. Is field Set not supported for Order Item? If not, then what could be the other way to have dynamic fields?

Comment: Sandeep, good news. Salesforce have added support for fieldsets for OrderItem object.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has decided to challenge us again. FieldSets are available for Order and Order Products objects. I am sure in future it will.. please vote for this idea: [Adding Field Set for Order Item](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96896/adding-field-set-for-order-item)